# Hiding the generating token in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf

I used the codeigniter and enabled csrf protection. I used form helper to generate the token.

But this token is clearly visible when viewing the source code in the browser.

Is my code prevent csrf attacks ? If not how to hide this token?

my code;

```
<?php
     $attributes = array('name' -> 'login_data');
     echo from_open_multipart('loader/login_screen_flow',$attributes);
?>

     form contents.....

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This code auto regenerates this;

```
<input type="hidden" name="token_name" value="hashed_token_name" >
```

how to hide this hashed code or token?

Comment: add form content as well

Comment: You cannot hide the token.

Comment: @Abdulla it is a simple login form

Comment: i need this code `form contents`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Please can you explain why? or give a reference .. It will be a great help

Comment: Simply because anything on the client can be controlled by the user. So if someone wants the token, he will get it, since you are sending it to the client to prevent CSRF by sending forms with tokens.

Comment: @saku. it's all on client side. even if you try hard to hide.. there will be visible for some people

Comment: You are doing the correct things to prevent CSRF problems. It does not matter that the token is visible in the browser. [A Useful Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: You cannot remove or hide csrf token because it is already hidden.Why you want to remove. form is validated by matching this form token and your session token.so let it be in the form and validate your form submission in server side.